# Java: Skydiving

Tags: java, loops, math

Sorry for lack of details, I made a few edits.

I've got a problem in my java class that I can't wrap my head around.

I need to make a program that draws random numbers which are formations in a 10 round competition. 
In this competition judges score you based on the formations you draw.
You can only have 5 or 6 points per round. You can only have 6 points if you draw 3 - 2 point formations.

The range of formations is 1-38.
Formations 1-16 are worth 1 point.
The rest are worth 2 points.

I tried this.

```
    int formation;
    int points;
    int round;
    boolean isOnePoint;
    int maneuvers = 0;
    public void main(String args[]){

        while(points < 5){
            getRandomFormation();
            if(points < 5 && isOnePoint){
                points++;
            }
            else if(points == 4 && !isOnePoint && maneuvers < 3){
                points +=2;
            } maneuvers++;
        }
    }

public void getRandomFormation(){
    formation = rand.nextInt(38);
    if(formation < 17){ isOnePoint = true; } else isOnePoint = false;
}
```

The problem I am facing is with this code that I came up with I am still able to get something like:

// example of output round with points recieved
Round 6: 1, 2, 1, 2

The problem however, is that you cannot get 6 points with anything other than getting three random 2 point combinations...
What am I overlooking / missing in my code to be able to get it right?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, to include more details - the scopes of all these variables, and methods. Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? Voting to close for lack of details.

Comment: You talk about 5 to 6 points, and then you talk about 3-2 points and also 1 to 2 points, but it's not clear how any of those are related or where you get them from. Posting a short complete program with desired and actual output would also help us identify where your problem might be. A partial code snippet tends to leave too many questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off what you have posted you seem to only want three numeric values.

Change your `while(points<5)` to `while(maneuver<3)` and increment maneuver at the end of the loop.

That would be the quickest way to solve your problem. The logic in your if statements are quite convoluted. You only check to see the number of maneuvers in the second if statement which means that you can still meet the parameters for the first if.

```
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        getRandomFormation();
        if(isOnePoint)
            points++;
        else 
            points +=2;
        }
```

Comment: I had the maneuvers wrong... i set it to 0 at the beginning of the round, should have put it to 1, I spent days looking for what i did wrong